# How to adjust the size of the boxplot frame in R to fit the plotted box

Tags: r, boxplot, frame-size

I am trying to plot a boxplot (just a single box, i.e 1 data column) but the issue I am having is that the frame enclosing the boxplot is so big compared to the actual plot/box which is in the middle. I would like to reduce the size of the frame without reducing the size of the plotted box so that the plotted box size is relative to the frame enclosing it.

For example, in this image

[image: figure example]

you can see the box is in the middle but there is a lot of space to the left and right of the box. So is there a parameter/s to make the frame size relative to the size of the plotted box? I tried to play around with a lot of parameters by setting them as arguments in `par()` function but I was not successful.

This code illustrates the problem:

```
x = data.frame(a = 1:15) 
boxplot(x, boxlwd = 2, outwex = 0.5, boxwex = 0.2)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code which you tried?

Comment: So I added the two lines of code that can generate similar figure, there is no much code really to create that boxplot, I believe it is just a parameter that I need to set/change to adjust the frame size. Thanks!

Comment: Try using the `boxplot(x, width = 1)`.  This might work for you.

Comment: Huh. While I was trying before, I did set the width parameter, but I think because I also set the boxwex parameter, it did not do anything. Using just the width parameter as you suggested kinda works but it makes the plotted box bigger to fill the empty space on the left and right. I wonder if there is a way to make the frame smaller for efficient use of the space?

Comment: Defining the plot first `plot(1, type="n", xlab="X", ylab="Y", ylim=c(0, 15), xaxt="n")` and then adding the boxplot `boxplot(x, width=1, add=T)` should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the plot margins using these parameters, here are margin values that work with the example. Increasing the margin size reduces the size of the plot frame.

```
x <- data.frame(a = 1:15)

par(mar = c(1, 19, 1, 19))  # Set margins (bottom, left, top, right)

boxplot(x, boxlwd = 2, outwex = 0.5, boxwex = 0.2)
```

[image]